# Jetpack Compose: TextAlign (Center vertically) of SpanStyle

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to implement `Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL` when using `SpanStyle`?

Do not use other Container Composables like `Box`, `Row`, etc...

```
val spanString = buildAnnotatedString {
    withStyle(
        SpanStyle(
            color = Color(0xFF333333),
            fontSize = 32.sp
        )
    ) {
        append("Jetpack")
    }
    withStyle(
        SpanStyle(
            color = Color(0xFF999999),
            fontSize = 14.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )
    ) {
        append(" Compose")
    }
}
Text(
    modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.White),
    text = spanString
)
```

Now:
[image: Img]

Expect:
[image: Img]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your second `SpanStyle`

```
 baselineShift = BaselineShift.Superscript
```

Modified code

```
 val spanString = buildAnnotatedString {
        withStyle(
            SpanStyle(
                color = Color(0xFF333333),
                fontSize = 32.sp
            )
        ) {
            append("Jetpack")
        }
        withStyle(
            SpanStyle(
                baselineShift = BaselineShift.Superscript, // added line
                color = Color(0xFF999999),
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
            )
        ) {
            append(" Compose")
        }
    }
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.White),
        text = spanString,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )
```

[image]